# GDAL: Install GDAL on AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, gdal

I have tried:

```
sudo yum install gdal
sudo yum install gdal-libs
```

and couple of other commands.
Is there an easy way to install gdal and then python gdal libraries on Amazon Machine Instance?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I am using elastic beanstalk, but I can't even get it to work on a default AMI instance. @Gnafu's comment didn't work for me.

Comment: reluctantly I had to use ubuntu. But if you find a solution do post.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do `sudo yum install gdal` after enabling the EPEL repo with

`sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel`